# How to set new array if unserialize string changed by user

Tags: php

```
$apply_id=25;

if(isset($_COOKIE['apply'])){$apply_cookie=$_COOKIE['apply'];}
else{$apply_cookie=serialize(array());}

$apply_cookie=unserialize($apply_cookie);

//HAVE COOKIE
if(in_array($apply_id, $apply_cookie)==TRUE){echo "COOKIE=TRUE<BR>"; print_r($apply_cookie);}
else{
    //NO COOKIE,DB HAVE RECORDED
    $db=FALSE;//I don't want to query, so just set TRUE FALSE
    if($db==TRUE){
        echo "COOKIE=FALSE; DB=TRUE";

        $apply_cookie[]=$apply_id;
        $apply_cookie=serialize($apply_cookie);

        setcookie("apply", $apply_cookie);

    }
    else{
        //NO COOKIE,NO RECORDED
        echo "COOKIE=FALSE, DB=FALSE";

        $apply_cookie[]=$apply_id;
        $apply_cookie=serialize($apply_cookie);

        setcookie("apply", $apply_cookie);
            //process the apply query...
    }
}
```

I have set up a cookie for my apply button, if  user have been apply, it will pop message instate to query again, if no cookie, it will check db and update cookie.

I store array(unserialize) into cookie and I use in_array to check.

**However if user try to change my cookie, unserialize will get error.**

Is any way to set up like- `if unserialize=FALSE apply_cookie=array();`

something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unserialize` returns `false` if it fails.

```
$apply_cookie = @unserialize($apply_cookie);
if ($apply_cookie === false) {
  $apply_cookie = array();
}
```

Comment: what is @ before unserialize for?

Answer (score 1):

> use `@unserialize`, the "`@`" infront of a function will silence errors

```
<?php
  $apply_id = 25;
  if ( isset( $_COOKIE["apply"] ) ) {
    $apply_cookie = $_COOKIE["apply"];
  }

  $apply_cookie = ( isset( $apply_cookie ) ) ? @unserialize( $apply_cookie ) : array();
  $apply_cookie = ( is_array( $apply_cookie ) ) ? $apply_cookie : array();

  //HAVE COOKIE
  if ( in_array( $apply_id, $apply_cookie ) ) {
    echo "COOKIE=TRUE<BR>";
    print_r( $apply_cookie );
  }
  else {
    //NO COOKIE,DB HAVE RECORDED
    $db = false;
    if ( $db === true ) {
      echo "COOKIE=FALSE; DB=TRUE";
      $apply_cookie[] = $apply_id;
      $apply_cookie = serialize( $apply_cookie );
      setcookie( "apply", $apply_cookie );
    }
    else {
      //NO COOKIE,NO RECORDED
      echo "COOKIE=FALSE, DB=FALSE";
      $apply_cookie[] = $apply_id;
      $apply_cookie = serialize( $apply_cookie );
      setcookie( "apply", $apply_cookie );
      //process the apply query...
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE`.
To `unserialzie` user inputs is VERY DANGEROUS.

unserialize
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

> **Warning**
>   Do not pass untrusted user input to **unserialize()**.
>   Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to
>   object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able
>   to exploit this. Use a safe, standard data interchange format such as
>   JSON (via **json_decode()** and **json_encode()**) if you need to pass
>   serialized data to the user.

If you defined like the following class:

```
<?php

class TestClass {

    public function __destruct() {
        echo '__destruct() called';
    }

}
```

And if you get serialized data:

```
O:9:"TestClass":0:{}
```

It will be displayed, `__destruct() called`.

Comment: Sessions don't last as long as cookies.

Comment: why this is dangerous? its only check for query, TRUE or FALSE, if FALSE, than query, its not input into my database

Comment: anyone can explain why this is dangerous? any example?

Comment: The explanation is in the answer.

Comment: I didn't use any class in my code, so is this still matter? Im not very good at class, how about PDO will unserialize affect PDO too? I found this post explain https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection