# Is serialize data dangerous with PDO

Tags: php, serialization, pdo

I have `8 input type text. name=favour_01`

I make those 8 `input` into an `array` and `serialize` it

i use `PDO` to save it into DB.

Than unserialize it for output

```
$favour[]='apple'; $favour[]='banana';

$favours = serialize($favours);

prepare(...

$food->bindValue(':favours', $favours, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

is this secure? I have read serialize input is vulnerable.

I didn't use any class for this, here is one post i have read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection

Comment: I don't think it's *dangerous*, but I do think you haven't grasped what good database design might look like...

Comment: one of my table have contain more than 30 columns, therefor I try to put those group input into an array

Comment: Um, joins? Relational databases?

Comment: if u have time, can u please help me have look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252769/how-to-set-new-array-if-unserialize-string-changed-by-user I make a cookie to reduce query

Comment: I did use join lol, it still very big

Comment: You haven't loaded the class definition.

Comment: i didn't use any class, just try to testing to see what happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing data is only a security risk when the data you serialize contains sensitive information.  The risk is that you serialize data that contains passwords for example and then you store the serialized form somewhere insecure.

*Unserializing* data is a security risk if you try to unserialize data that you got from an untrusted source.  The unserialization process can instantiate objects and the data input may therefore do things you don't anticipate.

What you're doing for serializing a simple array of values to bind it to a SQL parameter is okay from a security point of view, but keep in mind you won't be able to search the database efficiently for specific values within that serialized array.  Basically your database becomes a black box:  you can stuff a whole array into it, and fetch the whole array out to deserialize it, but you can't easily read or write individual elements of the array with SQL.

It's better practice to create a child table and store one element per row in that table.

Comment: thx u very much for answer, appropriate. I have the other cookie use serialize from my previous question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252769/how-to-set-new-array-if-unserialize-string-changed-by-user, but I'm not sure is this one ok or not, I have only learn OOP once and never use it, lol

Answer (score 2):

yes it is safe if you use prepared statement, then validate data after retrieving it from the database to  before output to browser.

Comment: when output to browser use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)