# PHP: Best way to store a session using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm at the point of my PHP based project where I need to store a session for user-login. I'm also using PDO.

I'm wondering what the best way of approaching this is though. I've read that if you simply use PHP's native `$_SESSION` variable and `serialize` it into an array, you loose the ability to subsequently query the database with the array created from serializing.

On the other hand, an unserialized `$_SESSION` posses a significant security risk.

See this answer here [Is serialize data dangerous with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253512/is-serialize-data-dangerous-with-pdo)

So I'm wondering what other options I have? Could I create a custom class function? What would be the best solution thats PDO based, secure and allows future database querying?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use PHP's native $_SESSION. That's all.

All your fears are groundless.

Look. After reading a lot of questions, you have got all the things intermixed in your head - sessions, PDO, serializing, security. While simple fact is: PHP's native $_SESSION is **perfectly secure** - otherwise there would be no sense in it. Yes, there are always some nuances. But starting with your **first session ever** you should use **nothing but native implementation**, to learn it, to make yourself familiar with it, to make yourself eventually understand it.

Comment: isn't an unserialized $_SESSION insecure?

Comment: well, write a session class in that case

Comment: You could always set an MD5 Session variable. :P

Comment: @user3143218 come on, at the level you ask it is perfectly secure. Frankly, you hardly understand every term you are using - so, it's quite toilsome a task to explain. Just leave your session as is and don't worry.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, if that's the case. Update your answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: That was actually a joke